# Changing Umbraco 7.1.4 admin URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to change the default admin UI URL used in Umbraco to a custom URL. The default URL is simply `/umbraco`, for example:

```
http://mywebsite.com/umbraco
```

As an example, I would like the admin UI URL to be:

```
http://mywebsite.com/asdf
```

So far, I have tried changing the umbracoPath app setting in the Web.Config:

```
<add key="umbracoPath" value="~/asdf" />
```

And renaming the 'Umbraco' folder to 'asdf' in my Visual Studio solution.

This gives some success, when navigating to `/asdf`:

[image: Attempt at changing URL]

However, the default admin UI page is blank. If I navigate to `/asdf#/umbraco`, then the expected default page is loaded:

[image: Attempt at changing URL 2]

I have obviously missed something, but cannot find what/where - how do I change the default admin UI URL to /asdf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the official Umbraco documentation you can do this one of two ways.

Firstly:

Add this rule to your "/config/urlrewriting.config" file

```
<add name="adminrewrite" 
    virtualUrl="^~/asdf/"       
    rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
    destinationUrl="~/umbraco/umbraco.aspx"
    ignoreCase="true" />
```

Secondly

Rename 'Umbraco' directory to 'asdf' then change your web.config file as below:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/asdf,~/install" />
<add key="umbracoPath" value="~/asdf" />
```

The second option is what you have already tried but I think it may be the reserved paths part that you are missing.

Just a word of warning, this has been rather a big issue since about version 4 and from the looks of things on the official community forums, this is still something that works for some people and doesn't work for others.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation you mentioned?

Comment: @PTuckley It appears he is referring to [this page](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/5050-Can-i-change-admin-panel-URL), which is actually a post on the Umbraco forums, not official documentation. It is of course possible that the referenced post did copy it from official documentation.

Comment: The post is from 2009 but as with most things to do with Umbraco, it is still of relevance today.

Answer (score 5):

I've found that renaming the Umbraco folder can have some adverse side effects. For example, if you use any packages developed by a third party some of them may have hard coded paths that require the Umbraco folder. If you can, a simple solution is to just create a 'asdf' virtual directory on the server and point it at the Umbraco folder. The Web.config and /Config/UrlRewriting.config changes are still necessary. I generally add to the reserved paths instead of replacing the umbraco item:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/asdf,~/umbraco,~/install" />
```